# PRODUCT IS NOT SUPPORTED (Visual Studio 2019)

Tags: windows, visual-studio, ide

I downloaded Visual Studio Community from [here](https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/vs/preview/) ,But getting this exception when installing.
Please let me know what could be the reason despite using latest version of windows.
I have also read [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/releases/2019/system-requirements) article , and using professional version of windows.

**Installer**

[image: Installer]

**System Configuration**

[image]

Comment: have you looked for the logs?

Comment: no i did not look

Comment: ok, please do this, otherwise I'll vote to close the question as "too broad" because we can't answer it without any new information.

Answer (score 4):

The 2015 in the System properties indicate you use a very old Windows 10 Version (TH1/TH2), but you need at least the Creators Update from March 2017:

> Visual Studio 2019 will install and run on the following operating
>   systems (64 bit recommended):
>
> **Windows 10 version 1703 or higher**: Home, Professional, Education, and Enterprise

So, update your [Windows 10 to the 1809](https://blogs.windows.com/windowsexperience/2018/10/02/how-to-get-the-windows-10-october-2018-update/).

Comment: look inside temp folder for VS installer logs. open them for more details.